# Create JSON in 2D array to store key value pair

Tags: java, arrays, json

I  have a question that would like to seek your expertise on.
I have Class call Technology and i retrieve data from the DB as object list of Technology class`technologyList= getProjectBD().getAllTechnology();`

my question is how to store data as key value pair in Json array.
This is my code

```
JSONArray technologyArray=new JSONArray();
for (Technology technology : technologyList) {
        JSONArray gridRow=new JSONArray();
        gridRow.put(technology.getTechnologyId());
        gridRow.put(technology.getTechnologyName());            
        technologyArray.put(gridRow);           
    }
```

I need to pass this data to select option in my jsp as id and name.
ex:-[1:JAVA,2:C#...]

Comment: Why not a JSONObject instead of JSONArray inside the loop?

Comment: You show the correct way sir.Thanxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `com.google.gson.*` elements like that :

```
private JsonArray serializetechnologies(List<Technology> technologyList) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    for (Technology technology : technologyList) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty(technology.getTechnologyId()+"", technology.getTechnologyName());
        jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

And if you want to get value :

```
for (JsonElement jsonElement : jsonArray) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonElement;
    String name = jsonObject.get(technologyX.getTechnologyId() + "").getAsString();
    System.out.println("The name of technology witch Id = " + technologyX.getTechnologyId() + " is : "
            + name);
}
```

I hope that will help :)

Comment: I need to access value using js Sir

Comment: This [link](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) expalins the concept of JS and JSP very clearly.