# convert list into JSON Format in spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

How can i get json data by using criteria projection in spring MVC project.
My Criteria Query as follows.

```
public List<Item> getProduct() {
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Item.class);
    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
    projList.add(Projections.property("item_code"));
    projList.add(Projections.property("item_name"));
    crit.setProjection(projList);
    List<Item> results = crit.list();
}
```

My Controller Class as Follows

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody List<Item> ProductList() {
        List<Item> productList = poService.getProduct();
         Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
         System.out.println("json = " + gson.toJson(productList));
        return productList;
    }
```

Output for this is

```
[[3,"CELLO PINPOINT"],[5,"JOHNSON BUDS 30"],[7,"SMALL WONDER FEEDING BOTTLE 125 ML"],[45,"YERA GLASS TUMBLER T70 6PC"],[1623,"PEPSI 500 ML"],[1816,"FOOD CHOPPER"],[1819,"SCREW SET"],[5653,"AMUL KOOL200ML"]]
```

Facing issue as not getting output as json format.

Comment: Why don't you build your own JSON like in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255808/create-json-in-2d-array-to-store-key-value-pair) ??

Comment: your output is actually a valid json string

Comment: @ Maraboc :I tried that one,but i am getting java.lang.ClassCastException:

Comment: if you have jackson in your classpath it should be done automatically

Comment: @Nikolay Rusev :yes i have

Comment: Sir,Is any other method to fetch 2 properties from table? Just like my above concept,except using entity manager

Comment: I'm really confused right now where is your problem...

Comment: Sir,First mentioned one is my problem

Comment: The output is a valid json. look at [this](http://www.json.org/) and you'll see that you have an array of arrays, and each item in the sub arrays are valid json elements such as number and string.

Comment: @ Avihoo Mamka: Sir,but i want my result as a collection of name/value pairs.